# Truecrypt error: the OSXFUSE file system is not available (255)

Tags: macos, encryption, truecrypt

My truecrypt files were mounting fine until today when I tried to mount it and I got the error: the OSXFUSE file system is not available (255). The weird thing is I honestly don't know what I could have done on my computer since yesterday when there were no problems that would have caused this. I tried deleting macfuse and osxfuse and redownloading both but it still doesn't work. The weird thing is when I remove OSXfuse it says it is not available (-1) and when I have it says the same thing but with (255). Is there anything I can do to get my files back? I am on mavericks if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I had the same issue, did you upgrade TrueCrypt?  If so you will need to update your encrypted volume.  I had almost the same error when I upgraded TrueCrypt then tried to mount an encrypted volume several weeks later - no go. I first tried to install the old version of TrueCrypt checked that the volume was still ok.  If that is not the issue then you may have to try restoring the volume, I don't think it is anything to do with osxfuse.  Also try reinstalling TrueCrypt. What verson of TC are you running?

Comment: I don't think I've updated TrueCrypt since the volume was mounting fine.  How would I restore the volume? I am using TrueCrypt 7.1.1

Comment: Do you use TimeMachine? I always backup my volume files, in fact I have three copies. One backup at the office, and one off-site, which I update once a month. If there is something critical going in there more often.

Comment: No I don't have any unencrypted backups.  I was hoping there was something I could do to fix this because it was working 2 days ago and now its not its so strange.  The only thing I can think of that has changed on my computer since two days ago is I installed parallels.  But that is it and I don't see why that would have an effect.

Comment: Installing parallels should not effect it.  I use VMware Fusion, and have never had any compatibility issues with TC. What about the encrypted volume - you should back up the ENCRYPTED volume, that way the backup is secure as well. You should always keep a backup, I have had a TrueCrypt volume get corrupted, moving from Android to OS X, but luckily I had the encrypted volume backed up. Having said that I would not give up hope.

Comment: Oh you think my problem may be with that specific encrypted volume and not a truecrypt compatibility with my computer for some reason?  I will definitely start backing up my encrypted volumes I'm just confused why all of a sudden it won't mount on my computer anymore.  Maybe it has something to do with the format? I use MAC OS instead of FAT

Comment: Yes, I think it an issue with the volume. I don't think it has anything to do with the format either.  FAT or Journaled etc should make no difference, TrueCrypt handles them all really well - it is very robust software.

Comment: I actually tried to make a new truecrypt volume and the same thing happened with the test volume! I can't mount any volume I am making on truecrypt now so I don't think it is just that my volume is corrupted.  I'm getting the same error for all volumes now even new ones.  So I feel like it must be an osxfuse problem right? or no?

Comment: If that is the case than that means that your volume is most probably not corrupted.  If the only change was Parallels then I would search that way and even contact their support.

Comment: When adding sudo kextutil -v /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/osxfusefs.kext
into terminal and then trying to mount any true crypt volume I then get the message hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems.  Any idea on what to do? I also have to put that into terminal every time I start my computer otherwise I get the OSXFUSE filesystems not available error message

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem today. I installed osxfuse and ntfs-3g via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), but I didn't install the kernel extension. I got a similar error message trying to mount an NTFS drive in RW mode. After installing the osxfuse kernel extension (instructions are available via `brew info osxfuse`), the error went away. Strangely, it didn't happen the first time I mounted an NTFS drive using ntfs-3g.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just installed Homebrew by typing: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" into terminal and I still can't mount the truecrypt volume.  I also can't make any new truecrypt volume because of the osxcuse filesystem error.  I don't get what has happened because everything was working fine a couple days ago.  With that generic install of homebrew does it also install the osxfuse kernel extension? If not how do I do that?  thanks

Comment: @user3255503 sorry, i'm just seeing this. you probably need to install osxfuse as well, with the command `brew install osxfuse`.

Comment: I was only able to install osxfuse using `brew cask install osxfuse`, I think osxfuse was migrated to cask